# check spen hardware feature availability in android programmatically

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am developing an app which lists all hardware features like WiFi, Bluetooth,NFC etc...

I am using `PackageManager.hasSystemFeature()` to check. 

Similarly Is there anyway to check whether a android device has a spen hardware support or not?
I need to check progrmmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is covered in the developer guide http://developer.samsung.com/:

```
boolean isSpenFeatureEnabled = false;
Spen spenPackage = new Spen();
try {
    spenPackage.initialize(this);
    isSpenFeatureEnabled = spenPackage.isFeatureEnabled(Spen.DEVICE_PEN);
} catch (SsdkUnsupportedException e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not support Spen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
    finish();
} catch (Exception e1) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot initialize Pen.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e1.printStackTrace();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the samsung spen sdk doesn't only support spen hardware.

For example if you try `spenPackage.initialize()` on an old Samsung model like S6 with no physical spen, the initialize() process would also be successful, and you would be able to utilize spen sdk with finger touch.